# Read Hbase table complete data to hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am trying to read the hbase table into hive.

I have tried below command for read complete table data.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_table_2(key int, value string) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = "cd:value")TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "companydetail", "hbase.mapred.output.outputtable" = "companydetail_hive");
```

cd is a columnfamily in my table, and its value.

Here problem is, when i run this command it only gives the particular value where i have mentioned in hbase columns mapping.

But i would like to load the complete table in hive which contains more than 5000 rows in hbase table, and also column family(cd) contains different column_prefixes.
I have tried what you have suggested but i still didnt get what i exactly need.

In my table column family is cd and table name is companydetail.

**Sample table data:-**

```
ROW                              COLUMN+CELL

\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\xA6 column=cd:cct, timestamp=1475738991531, value=Atlanta

\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\xA6 column=cd:cnt, timestamp=1475740226346, value=Network ICE Corp.

\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\xA6 column=cd:ct, timestamp=1475740596684, value=ISYI srl
```

I believe here **cct is a col_prefix**.

I have tried another way as below,

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_11(value map<string,int>, row_key int) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "hbase.columns.mapping" = "cd:cct.*,:key" );
```

**When i tried this, I get nothing. 0 records.** 
And here we are only giving the column family but we are not mentioning anywhere what is the table that we want to get the data.

I have tried an another way.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_table_1(value map<string,int>, row_key int) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "hbase.columns.mapping" = "cd:cct.*,:key" ) TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "companydetail", "hbase.mapred.output.outputtable" = "companydetail_hive");
```

I get the output as

```
{"cct":null}   NULL
{"cct":null}   NULL
{"cct":null}   NULL
{"cct":null}   NULL
{}   NULL
{"cct":null}   NULL
{}   NULL
{"cct":null}   NULL
{"cct":null}   NULL
{"cct":null}   NULL
{"cct":null}   NULL

Time taken: 0.45 seconds, Fetched: 1291 row(s)
```

**Table consist of 1291 rows, and if as i said cct is col_prefix for the table, then it is having 1291 col_prefixes.**

I cant get the whole table data because i have to do it for all the 1291 prefixes.

how can i do this,

Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.